# vbscript - Bring Internet Explorer Application window to front

Tags: vbscript, windows-7, internet-explorer-11

I have a script where I create an IE window through `CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`. The problem is, whenever I run this script, it always opens behind whatever else might already be open on my machine.  I want this IE window to open on TOP of everything else.  It does not have to be "always on top", like the option in Task Manager, but it should at least initially open on top. After that, I don't care what happens.  I have searched high and low and have been unable to find a way to achieve this.  I have tried `appactivate` and `focus()` but neither of those seem to work.  Any suggestions?

I am running Windows 7 with IE 11

Comment: When a program starts it has two seconds to set the foreground window.

Comment: Can you post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please?

Comment: What are you using after `AppActivate`? If you are using `"Internet Explorer"` or the equivalent, that could be your issue. I usually have to put the title (such as the value from: `IE.Document.Title`) after the `AppActivate`.

Comment: Or you could use `IE.Visible = True`

Comment: @Noodles do you have a *source* for that? First time I've heard it being that precise.

Comment: It's in the documentation for SetForegroundWindow (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx). There are 8 rules and you have to comply with one of the 8 to set the foreground window. Often people spend time doing stuff, like sleeping, then try to do activate a window after 2 secs have expired.

Comment: One quick fix is to `wshshell.popup "", 1` as a splash screen. Until the user clicks somewhere your program can set the foreground window.

Comment: @Lankymart I've posted those rules before.

Comment: @Noodles, thanks for your comment! I was sleeping while .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE before attempting to appactivate. I think that might have been the issue

Comment: Guessing if you set IE to visible straight that would comply - IE also has 2 secs to show a window.

Answer (score 7):

You probably have the problem because the title of the IE window is not exactly the title of the page (ie. "Yahoo - Internet Explorer")
Therefore you must bring it to the front before you start navigating to the page :

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").AppActivate "Internet Explorer"
ie.Navigate "http://www.yahoo.com/"
```

Comment: Funny, I thought I tried pretty much exactly this, but it didn't work before. I don't think I had used CreateObject("WScript.Shell") with appactivate, so that might have been it. It was either that or @Noodles comment on the time constraint on setting a foreground window. I had a sleep in there that might have been messing things up. Thanks!

Comment: IE doesn't need to be the foreground window to be controlled by script. It will work happily invisible.

Comment: @Noodles, yes, I am aware of that, but the whole point of the IE window for my application is to create a user interface to gather variable input to pass on to another application. I did not want the user of my script to have to try and find the IE window that my GUI is created in, I wanted that GUI to be immediately presented to them upon execution of my script. Thanks again for the insight regarding the time constrains on setting foreground windows!

Answer (score 1):

I found the sequence affects the behavior. Don't make IE visible until after it has finished loading.

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate "http://www.google.com"
While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend
ie.visible = True 
DoEvents
```

Comment: I know this is old, but this was a quick and easy way to avoid the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SetWindowPos API function to bring any window you want to front by its window handle.
The InternetExplorer object already has a property to call the handle(.Application.hwnd):

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
  ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, _
  ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2

Sub Test()
    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    ie.Visible = True
    SetWindowPos ie.hwnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE Or SWP_NOMOVE

    
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I messed around with a bunch of the solutions on the internet but eventually found the easiest one that worked.

```
Set objExplorer = CreateObject ("InternetExplorer.Application")
objExplorer.document.focus()
```

Comment: This results in an error: Compile Error: Syntax Error

Comment: Not for me Dave.  Which compiler are you using?   I'm using WScript.