# Open a PDF, select all text, copy, and paste special values

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am testing this code to open a PDF, select everything, copy, and paste special values into Excel.

```
Sub SelectCopy()

Dim myShell As Object
Set myShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
myShell.Run "C:\Users\rs\Desktop\test.pdf"

SendKeys "^a"   'Select All
SendKeys "^c"   'Copy
SendKeys "%{F4}"    'Close shell application
 
wkSheet.Range("A1").Select
SendKeys "^v"   'Paste

End Sub
```

When I get to this line...`SendKeys "^a"   'Select All`
It selects all the VBA code in the Module.

I tried Data > Import > PDF and it imports four tables from my PDF, but some of the data is getting truncated. If I open the PDF, hit Ctrl+A, then Ctrl+C, and got to Excel and hit Ctrl+V, I get exactly what I want.

Comment: something like this probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50818644/vba-set-focus-on-windows-application/50818830

Comment: `SendKeys` is not a reliable method. It acts on the window having focus.  You should try downloading PDF Creator, read about its SDK, add a reference to the necessary dll and do it in a proper/stabile way. Of course, you can reference `Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library` if Adobe Acrobat installed, but it is not free.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going with this solution.

```
Sub convertPDFtoTextViaWord()
   Const filePath As String = "C:\myfilepath\"
   Dim file As String, fileName As String
   Dim myWord As Word.Application, myDoc As Word.Document
   Set myWord = New Word.Application
   file = Dir(filePath & "*.pdf")
   myWord.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
   Do While file <> ""
       fileName = Replace(file, "pdf", "txt")
       Set myDoc = myWord.Documents.Open(fileName:=filePath & file, ConfirmConversions:=False, Format:="PDF Files")
       myDoc.SaveAs2 filePath & fileName, FileFormat:=wdFormatText, Encoding:=1252, lineending:=wdCRLF
       myDoc.Close False
       file = Dir
   Loop
   Set myDoc = Nothing
   Set myWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

With that little script, I can convert my PDF to a text file, and import the text file into Excel. Done.

Comment: Just to complete: to this code work you need to enable 'Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library'. Goes to the Visual Basic Editor, select Tools then References and scroll down the list until you see 'Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library'. Check that box and hit Ok. (Version may be different depending of the Office version you have.